# phone field can have 10 digits, if greater remove dashes

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to properly set format of a phone number focusing on 
1-777-777-7777? When I enter my phone number on the form field, the number is positioned like the following: "777-777-777". How can I get the number to position as "1-777-777-7777" and if greater dashes are removed.

Below is what I tried. I formatted the phone number, and have a validation of a certain amount  of numbers that can pass through validation. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your time. I have seen other forms, but not specifically as asked as this question. If anyone have resources feel free to provide.

```
function phoneFormat(input) {
  // Strip all characters from the input except digits
  input = input.replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Based upon the length of the string, we add formatting as necessary
  var size = input.length;
  if (size == 0) {
    input = input;
  } else if (size < 4) {
    input = '(' + input;
  } else if (size < 7) {
    input = '(' + input.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + input.substring(3, 6);
  } else if (size < 10) {
    input = '(' + input.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + input.substring(3, 6) + '-' + input.substring(6, 10);
  } else {
    input = input
  }
  return input;
}

function validatePhone(phoneNumber) {
  var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
  if (phoneNumber == "") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return phoneNumberPattern.test(phoneNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: With phone number validation, I've seen it said before that allowing the user to input any format is best, and when storing the number, strip everything but numerals out.

Comment: Also to check if phone number greater than 10 digits, assuming it's a string of digits and not letters, `if(phoneNumber > 9999999999)`

Comment: I agree with @JohnBell. You can perhaps have a separate input for country code (or have it as a dropdown list with your choice of country pre-selected)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd approach it a little differently, like this.

```js
const re_notADigit = /\D/g;
const re_stripTrailing = /[-)(]+$/g;

function phoneFormat(val) {
  let input = val.replace(re_notADigit, '');
  let size = input.length;

  if (size >= 11) {
    input = input.slice(0, 11);
    size = 11;
  }

  let prefix = "";
  if (size === 11) {
    prefix = input[0] + "-";
    input = input.slice(1);
  }

  return `${prefix}(${input.slice(0,3)})-${input.slice(3,6)}-${input.slice(6)}`
            .replace(re_stripTrailing, "");
}
```

```html
Enter phone number: <input oninput="value=phoneFormat(value)">
```